# Create JavaScript Function with Parameters from Array

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a function object in JavaScript from a string in an automated way, but I'm struggling a little with parameters. What I can do so far is the following:

```
var objectStr = "function(x) { return x; }";
var myFunc = Function("x", "{ return x; }");
```

If I make some assumptions, that the function will always start with "function(x)" I can do:

```
var objectStr  = "function(x) { return x;}";
var funcBody = objectStr.replace("function(x)", "");
var myFunc = Function("x", funcBody);
```

This gets me close to an automatic approach. I could also assign the string "x" to a value and pass that in as my parameter. However I really want to get to a place where I can provide the following:

```
var objectStr = "function(x, y) { return x*y; }";
```

At this point I want to extract out the parameters, x and y into a string array. I'm sure I could do this with regex quite sensibly.

```
var parameters = [ "x", "y" ];
```

But the question is, how do I now create a function, with multiple parameters, from my array of parameters?

**EDIT**

The reason for wanting to do this is to generate a function, for a callback. I have no control over the values of these parameters. A jQuery example to illustrate (although this isn't the library I'm using) might be:

```
// Define myFunc using approach above
// then somewhere later in 3rd party code an itterator block
// like below will call:
jQuery(data).each(function() {
    myFunc(this);
}
```

Comment: You do know you do not have to declare the arguments on a function but can still access them (however many get sent to your function) right?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I've added an edit to help illustrate my use-case. I have no control over the values of the parameters, they will be assigned based on 3rd party code and a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var parsedParameters = ["x", "y"];
var parsedBody = "return x*y";
var func = Function.apply(null, parsedParameters.concat(parsedBody));
    /*function anonymous(x,y) {
        return x*y
    }*/
```

It works because:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.1

> 15.3.1 The Function Constructor Called as a Function
>
> When Function is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initialises a new Function object. Thus the function call
>   Function(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new
>   Function(…) with the same arguments.

So one doesn't have to use `new`, which enables the use of `.apply`. `.apply` is used to call a function with the arguments coming from an array. See [Function#apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

The array in the example passed to `.apply` after `.concat` is:

```
["x", "y", "return x*y"]
```

So the static equivalent is `new Function("x", "y", "return x*y")`

Comment: That's a nice answer, a colleague mentioned Apply, but I pointed out that was for invocation of the function, not initialization. I guess a bit more understanding of the spec and I'm away. I'm just trying to google - but you may know. Do older browsers (IE8) behave to this spec?

Comment: @Ian Well works in IE7 at least. The reason you can use `.apply` is because `Function()` works the same as `new Function()`. You cannot use `.apply` if you needed to use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using eval e.g.  http://jsfiddle.net/tXe9T/:

```
var objectStr = "function(x) { alert (x); }";
var evalStr = "var myfunc = " + objectStr;
eval(evalStr);
myfunc("HI");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use eval do evaluate your function. like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/3Qpfx/

```
var funcMultipleParam = "function(x,y) {return x*y;}",
    FuncMultiple = eval("(" + funcMultipleParam + ")");

alert(FuncMultiple(10, 20));
```

Hope that helps.

Suj